# How to start with 2D

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

Ok my question is simple:
How do I start working with 2D graphics on android? Untill now,I found on the how to make almost anything on Android,however with graphics I see is harder.

On the android sdk website,I get some simple codes that don't really help me,and I also searched for a book,guess what,I didn't find one that actually shows you how to make a little game explaining me what does every line of code.

So: How do I start working with 2D graphics? I'm interested because I want to make some games.I would be very happy to find a tutorial for ex. that shows you how to make a little character that just jumps over a box.I know you need an engine and all that stuff,and I would actually want to learn how to make a little engine.

Answer (score 2):

[libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) runs on Android (and a few other platforms) and provides high level 2D graphics features like sprites, fonts, tile maps, particles, etc.

Tutorials [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?cat=17).

A few complete demo games with source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/#svn/trunk/demos).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [whole series](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html) that seems pretty decent, and starts from the beginning.

Also, the techniques of "generic" 2D programming apply, so general-purpose game engine information is useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in android games(2d), I recommend this book [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430230428/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428)

Answer (score 0):

The following book is very good for learning 2d graphics in Android.
"Android 2D graphics with Canvas API".

[http://www.amazon.com/Android-Graphics-Canvas-API-ebook/dp/B00DKIAVK8/ref=sr_1_8?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1374420538&sr=1-8&keywords=android+2d](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DKIAVK8)

It is not for game developers though.

It teaches how to use graphics primitives and work with different coordinate systems. It also has a chapter on multithreading.
It has many simple examples good for beginners.